# Django templates escape filters issue

Tags: python, django, django-templates, xss

I am trying to avoid XSS on my website. for testing purpose, I gave a username like this:

`ali <script>alert('xss not escaped')</script>`

and in my template I tried **escape** and **force_escape** filters but none of them is working.

Here is Django template code:

```
<label for="user_name" id="user_name_label" class="user-name font-weight-samibold mb-0">
     {{ username | force_escape }}
</label>
```

I am not able to understand, why these filters are not working, each time when the page is loaded, alert box appears.

Comment: I checked on my machine, it works - -.

Comment: But it does not work for me. basically I have 4 occurrences of it on my page. two are label, 1 is input value and 1 is data attribute in input tag. I have escaped all occurrences but in vain. @mi

Comment: you turned off the autoescape mannualy?